# Error "ORA-20001: Latest xml inventory is not loaded into table" while doing datapatch verbose in oracle patch upgrading

Tags: oracle, database-administration, oracle19c

`Hi All,

I was getting below below error while upgrading oracle from 19.3 to 19.20 but i was able to proceed after provideing jdk arguments explicitly.

Error:

```
/data/LINUX.X64_193000_db_home/OPatch/opatch: line 843: [: too many arguments
/data/LINUX.X64_193000_db_home/OPatch/opatch: line 843: [: too many arguments
Java (1.7) could not be located. OPatch cannot proceed!
```

Succeeded with jdk argument:

```
$ORACLE_HOME/OPatch/opatch apply -jdk $ORACLE_HOME/jdk
```

but after this, I am getting below error while trying to apply datapatch -verbose.

**Error with data patch verbose:**

Connecting to database...OK
Gathering database info...done
Bootstrapping registry and package to current versions...done
Error: prereq checks failed!
verify_queryable_inventory returned ORA-20001: Latest xml inventory is not loaded into table
Prereq check failed, exiting without installing any patches.

Please refer to MOS Note 1609718.1 and/or the invocation log
/data/app/oracle/cfgtoollogs/sqlpatch/sqlpatch_770698_2023_09_13_12_44_11/sqlpatch_invocation.log
for information on how to resolve the above errors.

SQL Patching tool complete on Wed Sep 13 12:44:13 2023

As per google solution, I tried to execute query : select * from OPATCH_XML_INV ;
which again gives same problem.
select * from OPATCH_XML_INV ;
ERROR:

```
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEFETCH callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-04095: preprocessor command
/data/LINUX.X64_193000_db_home/QOpatch/qopiprep.bat encountered error
"/data/LINUX.X64_193000_db_home/OPatch/opatch: line 843: [: too many arguments
/data/LINUX.X64_193000_db_home/OPatch/opatch: line 843: [: too many arguments
```

**Question:**

1. How to resolve this problem?
2. Is data patch -verbose execution is required as my current patch level is already showing 19.20?

I observed that issue is with finding java version or with java home so i already tried hardcoding JAVA_HOME in opatch.`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and its not installing the patches because data patch is not running.

SELECT TO_CHAR(action_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS action_time,
action,
status,
description,
patch_id
FROM   sys.dba_registry_sqlpatch
ORDER by action_time;SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL>   2    3    4    5    6    7

ACTION_TIME  ACTION     STATUS     DESCRIPTION                                                    PATCH_ID

---

2023-10-26   APPLY      SUCCESS    Database Release Update : 19.3.0.0.190416 (29517242)           29517242

SQL>
SQL>

issue is the exact thing you mentioned, JAVA_HOME is not getting interpreted correctly, workaround for this is I edited qopiprep.bat file, in the qopiprep.bat also we are calling the opatch:

```
$ORACLE_HOME/OPatch/opatch lsinventory -customLogDir $ORABASE/rdbms/log -jdk $ORACLE_HOME/jdk -xml $ORABASE/rdbms/log/xml_file_${DBSID}_${PD}.xml -retry 0 -invPtrLoc $ORACLE_HOME/oraInst.loc >> $ORABASE/rdbms/log/stout_${DBSID}_${PD}.txt
```

RETVAL=$?;